# Expected Value of Normal Random Variable times its CDF

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expectation

As usual, let $\Phi$ and $\varphi$ denote the cumulative density function and the density function of a standard normal random variable.

On the wiki page "[List of integrals of Gaussian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions)", I have found an expected value integral involving  a standard normal r.v. **and** its cdf,

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\varphi(x)\Phi(a+bx)dx=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\varphi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right),$$

for which I do not know how to do the last step in my solution:

My ansatz is to introduce a parameter integral, $I:=I(a)$, and finding its derivative:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\varphi(x)\varphi(a+bx)dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2(1+b^2)+2abx+a^2\right)}}{2\pi}dx\\
&=a\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{1+b^2}}}{\sqrt{1+b^2}\sqrt{2\pi}}\\
&=a\frac{\varphi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}
\end{align*}
$$

Integrating the derivative, we obtain:

$$
\begin{align}
I&=\int \frac{\partial I}{\partial a}da + C\\
&=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\varphi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)+C,
\end{align}
$$

which equals the solution on the wiki page plus a constant term $C$. From here on, I do not know how to get rid of the integration constant, i.e. how to show that $C=0$.

I do know that for $b=0$ it holds that $I=0$. Is this be sufficient to pin down $C$ to zero? Or do I miss something completely?

Comment: I haven't thought much about it, and this goes in the opposite direction of your proof, but would it be fruitful to write $\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \phi(y) dy$ so that $I$ is a double integral with an easier (probabilistic) interpretation?

Comment: I have tried this as well, but it did not bring me closer to a solution.

Comment: You can set $b=0$ to get $C=0$. The reason why that is allowed is because the equality must hold for all $b$. So choosing $b=0$ gives you the result.

Comment: @Shashi, thank you very much. I'd consider this an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from parameter integral, we can solve the problem from the perspective of probability theory. Notice that

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\Phi(a+bx)\varphi(x)dx = \mathbb{E}[X\Phi(a+bX)]$$

Let's say X and Z are independent standard normal variables, we have

$$\Phi(a+bX) = \mathbb{P}(Z\leq a+bX|X) = \mathbb{E}[1_{\{Z\leq a+bX\}}|X]$$

, then

$$\mathbb{E}[X\Phi(a+bX)] = \mathbb{E}\left[X\cdot\mathbb{E}[1_{\{Z\leq a+bX\}}|X]\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[X\cdot1_{\{Z\leq a+bX\}}|X]\right]$$

For any random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$, applying the law of total expectation, we have

$$\mathbb{E}\xi = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E[\xi|\eta]}\right]$$

Using the upper equality for $\xi=X\cdot1_{\{Z\leq a+bX\}}$ and $\eta=X$, we obtain that

$$\mathbb{E}[X\Phi(a+bX)]=\mathbb{E}[X\cdot1_{\{Z\leq a+bX\}}]$$

Next, all we need to do is to calculate the double integral, for convenience, let's say $a>0$ and $b>0$(details as follows)
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[X\cdot1_{\{Z\leq a+bX\}}]&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\int_{\frac{z-a}{b}}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dxdz\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(z-a)^2}{2b^2}}dz\\
&=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{(1+b^2)}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(z-\frac{a}{1+b^2})^2}{\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}}}dz\\
&=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{a^2}{(1+b^2)}}\\
&=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\varphi(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}})
\end{split}
Note that, for other values of a and b, the deduction above also applies.

Comment: +1 very elegant solution