# Expected Value of Exponential of Normal Random Variable times its CDF

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $\Phi$ and $\varphi$ denote the cumulative density function and the density function of a standard normal random variable. I'd like to calculate

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{cx}\varphi(x)\Phi(a+bx)dx.$$

This is similar to [Expected Value of Normal Random Variable times its CDF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555218/expected-value-of-normal-random-variable-times-its-cdf) where the term $e^{ax}$ is replaced with a linear term. Tried to apply similar tricks here but didn't work out.

Comment: Be careful.  You need restrictions on the parameters to get a finite $I$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Can you explain a bit more about your insight? For finite $a, b, c$ the integral can be infinity?

Comment: Write $e^{ax} \psi=e^{ax} e^{-x^2}$ (with constants). Complete the square in the exponent. Change variable $u=x+\text{const}$ so that the ($u$ dependant) exponential term looks like $e^{-Cu^2}$. Now you have an [integral of Gaussian and error function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028788/integrating-frac12-sigma-sqrt2-pi-int-infty-infty1erf-fracz-mu-i/4031039#4031039) of the form $e^{-Cu^2}\operatorname{erf}(A+Bu)$. $A$, $B$, and $C$ are related to your original constants. I'm not sure how the integral could diverge as $e^{ax}$ is swamped by the Gaussian for large $|x|$

Comment: @Yuan Gao  My error.  I forgot the $e^{-x^2}$ term.

Answer (score 0):

This integral evaluates as
$$
e^{c^2/2}\Phi\left(\frac{bc+a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)\,.
$$
I do not see a restriction on the parameters. I suggest to verify this with a simple python program before we get into the details of the proof.